# Golang struct with type Error property JSON response always empty even tho struct prints error message to console

Tags: go, go-gin

I have a custom Response struct to use in my gin controller. That Response has a field of type Erorr which I am populating inside my services method. I then check if the response object error is nil or not and it works when I print into console. The JSON objects Error is always empty tho and I dont seem to find any reason why so.

```
type RequestResponse struct {
    Status     int         `json:"status"`
    Data       interface{} `json:"data"`
    Error      error       `json:"error"`
    Pagination Pagination  `json:"pagination"
}
```

Controller

```
func GetTickerBySymbol(c *gin.Context) {

    symbol := c.Param("symbol")
    response := models.GetTickerBySymbol(symbol)

    if response.Error != nil {
        fmt.Println("error occured")    //gets printed to console
        fmt.Println(response.Error) //gets printed to console = "r"ecord not found"
        response.Status = http.StatusBadRequest
        response.Data = nil
        c.AbortWithStatusJSON(response.Status, response)
    } else {
        response.Status = http.StatusOK
        c.IndentedJSON(response.Status, response)
    }
}
```

Inside the controller function the error gets printed by FTM but my JSON API response always looks like this in case of an error

```
{"status":400,"data":null,"error":{},"pagination":{"page":0,"totalPages":0,"totalElements":0}}
```

Comment: The output will depend on the _dynamic_ type of the `error` value; And in your case the `{}` suggests that it is a struct type (or more likely a pointer to a struct type) with __unexported fields__ (which is why the object is empty). Note that the `fmt` package automatically calls the `.Error() string` method when it encounters values of type `error`, however the `encoding/json` package will NOT do that, instead it will marshal the `error`'s dynamic type according to the rules outlined in the [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json@go1.21.1#Marshal).

Comment: See example: https://go.dev/play/p/13yDBzqIK7a

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your function `models.GetTickerBySymbol` is initializing `RequestResponse.Error` with an empty struct `{}`.

The hint is that `c.AbortWithStatusJSON(response.Status, response)` renders `response.Data` as `"data":null` but `response.Error` as `"error":{}`.

Comment: But even if its an empty struct on initialization, at some point I am assigning the error to that key so shouldnt that be inside then?

Comment: You should initialize it with `nil` and only assign the error struct if an error occurs. 
I'm guessing that you don't have an error but rather initialized with the wrong type.

Then `if response.Error != nil {` will evaluate to `if {} != nil {` which is true.